# Is there a prohibition to eat produce before bikkurim (first fruits) have been separated?

Tags: halacha, maaser-tithes, bikkurim-first-fruits

[Rambam Sefer Hamitzvos negative command 153](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961797/jewish/Negative-Commandment-153.htm) says

> We are forbidden from eating tevel, i.e. produce from which the
>   terumos1 and ma'asros have not yet been separated.

Is there a comparable prohibition of eating produce before bikkurim (first fruits) have been separated? Would such produce be “tevel”?

Comment: parallel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8946/759

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's not forget the next prohibition on the Rambam's list ([#154](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961798/jewish/Negative-Commandment-154.htm)):

> The 154th prohibition is that we are forbidden from giving the agricultural gifts out of order; rather, we must give them in the proper order.

Separating Terumot and Maaserot before separating Bikkurim violates one of the 613 Torah commandments (Mishna Terumot 3:6-7). So in practice your question is rarely relevant.

The Mishna in Bikkurim ([2:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37940&st=&pgnum=346),5) list that one of the differences between Bikkurim and Teruma/Maaser is that only the latter אוסרים את הגורן prohibit the grain. Rambam there in his commentary explains:

> הוא שאסור לאכול דבר מן הגורן עד שיוציאם ד״ל התרומה והמעשר לפי שהוא טבל ואינו כן בבכורים
>   It is forbidden to eat from the pile (of produce) until one removes them, the Teruma and Maaser that is, for it is Tevel; but it is not so regarding Bikkurim.

Some explain that particular Mishna differently, but I don't think anyone disputes this halachic point. No mention is made of Bikkurim in Rambam's presentation on the prohibition of eating Tevel (Maachalot Asurot 10). Moreover in Bikkurim 2:19 Rambam cautions against separating Bikkurim from impure produce because there is no point to doing so, implying there is no prohibition on consumption to be lifted.