# Property border trees and Peah

Tags: gezel-stealing, agriculture, masechet-peah

Are fruit trees used to demarcate the border between properties considered to be in *peot hasadeh* (corners of the field, see Vayikra 19:9 and 23:22, Masechet Peah)?

If they are considered to be *peot hasadeh*, their fruits would be free to take (assuming that all other applicable agricultural halachot are followed). However, if they are not of the *peot*, then it might be considered theft to take the fruit.

Answer (score 3):

Peah has to be designated by the owner.  It also doesn't have to be in the corner of the field, but it does have to be at the end of the owner's harvest.  (Peah 1:3)

Also, even if it is designated, you can only take it if you're poor (this is in the pesukim you quoted, Peah 8:8 gives the criteria to be poor).

Peah also only applies to a few kinds of trees (Peah 1:5).  For example figs and apples are excluded.

Comment: That'd be Rambam Matenot Aniyim 2:12-14

Comment: Peah does apply in Israel and the diaspora currently. If no one shows up to take it then the owner of the field can reclaim it, just like always, and if a poor person does show up then they get to take it, just like always. Most poor people nowadays don't have time to go hang out near fields for weeks to get some raw wheat. I've heard that in some places in Israel poor people send messengers (ie. Tzedaka organizations) to go collect it.

Comment: @DoubleAA you've been skeptical of the same point before https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/does-kashrut-depend-on-peah-leket-etc#comment30398_8953, but they do quote the Chazon Ish to that effect.  I don't have it with me.  It's also possible that society has changed in the last 80 years and what he said is no longer true.

Comment: ברוך שכוונתי :) More likely is since 99.99% of cases involve no one showing up, Artscroll misrepresented the position. Just because it basically never happens doesn't mean it couldn't happen if a poor person decided he wanted to camp out near your field.

Comment: @DoubleAA side point but how do they send a shaliach?  Rambam matnot aniyim 2:19 paskens not like R' Eliezer in Peah 4:9.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, but whether or not a particular Ani was Zokhe via Shaliach doesn't seem as relevant here as whether Aniyim are claiming the food. The whole Heter for not leaving Peah if there aren't Aniyim is you don't need to leave it for birds to eat, but here birds won't eat it since the Aniyim will get it, even if they possibly aren't individually Zokhe till later at the soup kitchen. It could also be that a formal Gabbai Tzedaka can function as Yad Aniyim somehow different form regular Zakhin leAdam, but that would require more thought.

Comment: @DoubleAA I checked the Chazon Ish inside, maasrot 7:10.  There's not much more there than I already said.  My analysis is (1) in the Chazon Ish's time there wasn't an efficient way for the aniyim to take and use raw grain.  (2) as you say this is no longer true, in some places, for peah.  I imagine that the tzedakah organizations still don't bother with leket.  No idea how shichchah comes in practically with modern agriculture so I won't comment.  Could be they work in units bigger than סאתים since the machines are bigger so it never comes up.  (cont)

Comment: (3) point 1 probably never applied to peah for trees in a reasonably accessible location since the aniyim can just eat it on the spot.  (Peret and oleilot... maybe.  It's still not terribly efficient for the aniyim to look for them.  Shichchah, again, no idea.)  (4) in cases where point 1 applies, there's nothing further to discuss for leket, shichchah, peret, and oleilot since they take effect automatically.  (cont)

Comment: (5) צ"ע on peah, since לכאורה you should still have to declare it as peah.  The Chazon Ish says that these mitzvot are derabbanan nowadays, for reasons I didn't quite follow.  Maybe he understands that the derabbanan only applies in cases where the aniyim actually get it.